# How to make a steady supply of water from a supply of H2 and O2

Tags: reaction-mechanism, water

writing a survival novel where a guy needs to survive and needs to make water to do so.  It is on another planet and he access to sci-fi type manufacturing machines that can make most tings.

He has a supply of O2 and a supply of H2, lets assume at a reasonable temperature.

My understanding is that you mix the two together (preferrably two to one) and ignite it and this produces water in a sort of chain reaction.

Assuming this is done in an inclosed space, does all the H2 and O2 turn into water? Is the chamber left in a vacuum state or close to it after?  There is a lot of heat involved in this process I believe, does that mean the water comes out in the form of steam, or does something about this process end up cooling it into water droplets?

I figure I need to get the answers to some of these questions to be able go about creating a believable scenario.  BTW, please forgive me ahead of time, my chemistry knowledge is basically non-existent, I got what little I know here from googling.

---

As EdV mentioned in the comments, not premixing the gasses and them suppying them to an intense flame, will get the desired results without any unwanted explosions.  The result will be steam and a lot of heat.

Comment: The [fuel cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_cell) might be the way to go, as he'd get water and electricity in the process...

Comment: @ToddMinehardt Thanks, but far too complicated for my reader base.  I need a much simpler technique.

Comment: You would burn the two using a ‘glassblower’s’ torch, so the hydrogen and oxygen gases are not pre-mixed and you cannot have an explosion. You get steam and heat and then condense the steam to liquid water.

Comment: Recycle urine like the astronauts. Ed V has already given the answer.

Comment: In case you are wondering, a glassblower’s torch is a type of *total consumption burner*. By not pre-mixing, even explosive gas combinations, e.g., hydrogen and fluorine, could be burned. And other exotics, like oxygen and cyanogen. But exotic high temperature flames were made obsolete by argon inductively coupled plasmas, etc.

Comment: In case you want to further simplify things:   You don't even need purified oxygen.  Just burn the hydrogen with air (which can also be done with a glassblower's torch), using the right ratio of air to hydrogen needed to get complete combustion (about 2.5:1).  The key differences are that it would burn at a lower temperature, and you might get some nitrogen oxides (from the nitrogen in the air) that (depending on the concentration and toxicity) you might need to allow to vent.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt  you deleted my proposed answer, which is fair given you guys are the experts.  But that said, I got enough of what I wanted from this question and am unlikely to come back to it.  So not sure what you want to do here with the question, since apparently I wouldn't know what counted as a legitimate answer if it bit me in the face :)

Comment: Conversion of self-answers to selfcriticizing/clarification-requesting comments does not make much sense.

Comment: I didn't mean anything by it, was just wondering what should be done with the question and any potential answer.  Given that I might not be unqualified to even no what the correct answer is.  Should I just then ignore this question further and leave it 'unanswered'?  Should I 'transfer ownership' of the question?  (not even sure that's a thing).

Comment: @user2765977 It was flagged as such and I almost always defer to the members of the community here. I have undeleted your answer; I encourage you to accept your answer (as you may know, that is a thing) and please don't read anything into it. We welcome you and your presence here so don't be put off.

Comment: Hasn't this already be done in fiction? Check The Martian by Andy Weir (or the movie).

Answer (score 1):

As EdV mentioned in the comments, not premixing the gasses and them suppying them to an intense flame, will get the desired results without any unwanted explosions.  The result will be steam and a lot of heat.

Comment: Might as well use the steam to run a steam engine or water pump or grain mill, etc. Lots of possibilities.

Comment: Might be useful in your current or future writing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_hydrogen_technologies.